# El flujo de funciones se queda parado en C, usando DevC++

Tags: c, funciones

tengo el problema de que cuando ejecuto mi codigo, no me da ningun error o aviso, se sigue ejecutando las funciones hasta que llega a una. A partir de ahi ya deja de ejecutarse y se queda como esperando a que se introduzca algun dato, aun cuando en el codigo no hay ningun scanf o un getch.

En la imagen que adjunto se ejecuta hasta el bloque canprin()

Las funciones estan por aqui, yo las veo correctas

[image: Consola]

```c
int canprin() //TERMINADO
{   
    int tubo=3;
    int pauc=pau;
    if (pau<=10)
    printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 5 x50mm \n\n");
    if (pau<=20&&pau>=11)
    printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 6 x50mm \n\n");
    if (pau>=21&&pau<=30)
    printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 7 x50mm \n\n");
    if (pau>30)
    {
        do
        {
            if (pauc>15)
                tubo=tubo+1;
                pauc=pauc-15;
        }while (pau>0);

        if (tubo<6) {
            tubo=6;
        }

        pauc=pau;

        do 
        {
            if (pauc>=20)
                tubo=tubo+1;
                pauc=pauc-20;
        } while (pauc>0);

        printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): %d x50mm \n\n", tubo);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues me da que `pau` debería ser realmente `pauc`:

```
    do
    {
        if (pauc>15)
            tubo=tubo+1;
            pauc=pauc-15;
    }while (pau>0);
    //      ~~~
```

Son los riesgos de usar nombres incorrectos para variables y clases... es facil confundirse y luego el código no hace lo que esperamos.

Por otro lado, ojo con la tabulación del código. A simple vista podría parecer que el condicional afecta a dos instrucciones:

```
if (pauc>15)
    tubo=tubo+1;
    pauc=pauc-15;
```

Cuando realmente solo afecta a una de ellas... la otra simplemente está mal tabulada:

```
if (pauc>15)
    tubo=tubo+1;
pauc=pauc-15;
```

No es mala costumbre usar llaves incluso en los condicionales de una sola línea:

```
if (pauc>15)
{
    tubo=tubo+1;
}
pauc=pauc-15;
```

El problema con las tabulaciones es endémico en tu caso, deberías corregir eso.

Adicionalmente, nota que el condicional `if` no va solo... puede ir acompañado de `else`. Usar `if-else` tiene sus ventajas, como por ejemplo que no tenemos que comprobar varias veces lo mismo:

```
if (pau<=10)
    printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 5 x50mm \n\n");
else if (pau<=20 /*&&pau>=11*/) // Ahora nos sobra parte de la condición
  printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 6 x50mm \n\n");
else if (/*pau>=21&&*/pau<=30) // Y aquí también
  printf("CANALIZACIÓN PRINCIPAL TUBOS x DIÁMETRO): 7 x50mm \n\n");
else /* if (pau>30) */ // Y aqui nos sobra el condicional directamente
```

Comprobar varias veces lo mismo no es una buena idea, ya que si las condiciones cambian tienes que revisar una amplia extensión de código en vez de simplemente una línea.

Comment: Buenas tardes. He corregido el código tal y como me ha dicho y funciona perfectamente. Solo darle las gracias por ayudarme tan amablemente :)

Comment: Ahh! Y también me pondré a corregir mi problema con mis tabulaciones, siempre intento que mi código quede lo más legible posible y ahí fallo. Gracias igualmente